# Can't install Microsoft SQL Server because of VssAccessControl

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I've tried to install MS SQL Server Express(tried 2012 and 2014 versions) and in both of installers I've gotten the same problem:

> Could not write value NT SERVICE\SQLWriter to key \SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VSS\VssAccessControl.   Verify that you have sufficient access to that key, or contact your support personnel.

There is only this error in logs too.
I check this registry path and there is no this path at all(I guess that it is exactly the problem). How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Registry values example (they are from other computer, where MSSQL installed without problem)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwvwP.png)

Hello.

I had same problem on Windows 7 and MSSQL 2012 or MSSQL 2014 and finally found how to fix it.

First of all I set permissions and Owner as described [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e3eca667-d158-4e2f-b908-bd5e9cecb09c/error-installing-sql-server-writer-component?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade) but no success. I can not create "VSS\VssAccessControl" branch manually through Regedit. I had "VSS\Diag" branch with several subbranches (please see attached Diag.reg file). I can rename this "Diag" or its subbranches, but can not create "VSS\VssAccessControl". Strange...

Ok, so my recipe:
1. I have renamed Diag branch to VssAccessControl and started MS SQL setup. 
2. It failed with same error as you described. OK. Installation failed and I finished it. 
3. Registry refreshed and found what whole VSS branch was deleted. 
4. Now I created manually VSS branch and its subbranch VssAccessControl. It is not restricted.
5. I have added also DWORD32 keys with names: "NT SERVICE\SQLWriter" and "NT Authority\NetworkService" and set values to both of them to 1. (You can use vss.reg file provided below to avoid to make it manually) 
6. Started MSSQL setup again and it installed successfully.

Content of Diag.reg file or just export your own before step 1:

---

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VSS\Diag]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VSS\Diag\BITS Writer]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VSS\Diag\IIS Config Writer]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VSS\Diag\IIS Metabase Writer]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VSS\Diag\SqlServerWriter]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VSS\Diag\System Writer]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VSS\Diag\VolSnap]
"VolumesSafeForWrite (Enter)"=hex:48,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,81,77,bc,a9,e8,0e,d2,\
  01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,1e,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"VolumesSafeForWrite (Leave)"=hex:48,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,c9,f3,93,ca,e8,0e,d2,\
  01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,1f,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VSS\Diag\WMI Writer]

---

Content of vss.reg file:

---

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VSS\VssAccessControl]
"NT Authority\NetworkService"=dword:00000001
"NT SERVICE\SQLWriter"=dword:00000001

---

Comment: This is the only option working for me, after realizing it is not possible to install SQL server 2016 on Windows 11. After this attempt, I was repeatedly stuck unable to uninstall the SQL server again nor install SQL server 2019 and the VSS Writer kept running in the background and unable to be uninstalled. After successfully installing SQL server 2019 Developer edition, all components can be uninstalled.